# Zooming into a layout on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to zoom into my layout on double tapping the screen .(Layout containing buttons,images etc..).How do i acheive this on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this.How i have done this is i have created a custom layout that holds my image and buttons and when i zoom  I re-layout the custom layout .During the layout process i re-size the image and position the buttons accordingly.

Incase anyone has a better solution kindly let me know.

Thanks.